# How do I add text next to the image in a Bootstrap card?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put some text next to the image in a Bootstrap card. But the text ends up in the next line. Below is the CSS I used to resize the image to fit about half the width and the text is suppose to go in the other half. What CSS can I add to make the text float to the right of the image?

```
.card-img-top {
            height:150px;
            width:150px;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: use `float:left` in the css of the image (& .card-img-top if required). This enables the image to take only the space required but not the whole width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [flexbox utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) in this case as well.
Below is an example that uses `.d-flex .align-items-center` in order to vertically center the image and the text. Your actual implementation might change depending on your exact needs, but this is just to illustrate how to start.

```html
<div class="card w-50">
    <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-center bg-light">
        <div>
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/1f1a38/ffffff?text=Image" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <p class="col p-2 m-0">Text next to the right of the image</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with html:

```
<figure>
   <img .... >
</figure>
<h3> Text.... </h3>
<p> Text.... </p>
```